# Rending HTML pages using Plumber in R

Tags: r

I understand that plumber is more suitable to build an API than a full fledged website, this said I am trying to display the dynamic data from the db (mongo) in HTML. All works fine but the way I use (heavily inspired from a titanic example) might not be the best one. Here is an example of my homepage:

```
#' Return result
#' @get /
#' @serializer html

function(ht) {
  title <- "Title"
  body_intro <-  "Welcome to R.gift!"
  body_model <- paste("This is just a test ...page from the db with name <b>", single[1], "</b>")
  body_msg <- paste("the home page title is <b>", single[2] , "</b>",
                     "The home page content:<b>",
                     single[3], "</b>",
                     sep = "\n")


css <- ' <link href="https://cloud.typography.com/7/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">'
about <- '<a href="pages/about">about page</a>'
contact <- '<a href="pages/contact">contact page</a>'

  result <- paste(
    "<head>",
    css,
    "</head>",
    "<html>",
    '<div style="font-family: Giant Background A, Giant Background B;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;font-size:20pt;">',
    "<h1>", title, "</h1>",
    "<body>",
    body_intro, "</div>",
    '<div style="font-family: Gotham A, Gotham B;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;font-size:16pt;">',
    "<p>", body_model, "</p>",
    "<p>", body_msg, "</p>",
    "<p>", about, "</p>",
    "<p>", contact, "</p>",
    "</div>",
    "</body>",
    "</html>",
    collapse = "\n"
  )

  return(result)
}
```

so my question is if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same perhaps with a semi-templating system. The solution might be obvious (I am very new to R so bear with me). I know that plumber can server static files with

```
#* @assets ./files/static
list()
```

but I assume this wouldn't allow me to pass variables into index.html for example ?

The ideal scenario is having just tags like in any templating system.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
basicHTML <- "The home page title is <b> %s </b> The home page content: <b> %s </b>" # create a template in a file or in the script.

single <- c(title = "Hello World", bodyMsg = "lorem ipsum") # set up your parameters.

finalHTML <- sprintf(basicHTML, single[1], single[2])
```

Or maybe you feel more comfortable with this approach: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! so you would recommend using a separate file and then included it ?  how would %s bind directly to the variables? some more information would be very useful!

Comment: Using a separate file is the easiest way to maintain the code.

You can find more information about `sprintf` here [link] (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html)

Comment: at the moment I have the data in variables like single[1] single[2] etc. so how would I go producing the basic html file like %s and then the variable name? sorry for not getting it !  may be you could elaborate on my example ?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to do away with the server side rendering and do everything on the client side. You could use a frontend library like vue (if you understand HTML and basic javascript, you can use vue) and then do a GET request to the backend for the data you need. Then use that data to customize the UI. This approach let's R focus on data and the frontend focus on the presentation.